# Skipfish is not working. Error states: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, security, skipfish

I have tried multiple things for skipfish. I am trying to do a lab for my cybersecurity class and Skipfish is not cooperating. Here is the code we are supposed to be running. Please help me out.

`skipfish -o /home/student/Desktop/dvwaskipfish -A admin:password http://dvwa.example.com/login.php`

Every time I run the code, I get an error that says:

```
$ skipfish -o /home/student/Desktop/dvwaskipfish -A admin:password http://dvwa.example.com/login.php
skipfish web application scanner - version 2.10b
[-]   SYSTEM ERROR : Unable to Create '/home/student/Desktop/dvwaskipfish'.
     Stop location : main(), src/skipfish.c:571
        OS message : No such file or directory
```

I have tried other bits of code to possibly fix it but it gives me the same error. Here are the other code lines:

`sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev libidn11-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev build-essential zlibc zlib-bin libidn11-dev libidn11` This one gave me issues. Here is the error I received from it.

```
Package zlib-bin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  minizip

E: Unable to locate package zlibc
E: Package 'zlib-bin' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libidn11
```

Anyways, it is not working for me but seems to like another student in the class. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. Thank you!